# Spring boot embed tomcat - /pages/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Tags: jsf, tomcat, primefaces, spring-boot

I'm trying to develop a console made JSF2 end Primefaces that runs on an embedded tomcat in spring boot. This is my project configurations:

pom.xml

```
<parent>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
    <version>1.2.7.RELEASE</version>
    <relativePath /> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
</parent>

<properties>
    <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    <main.basedir>${basedir}/../..</main.basedir>
    <java.version>1.8</java.version>
    <tomcat.version>7.0.59</tomcat.version>
</properties>

<dependencies>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-juli</artifactId>
        <version>${tomcat.version}</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
        <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
        <scope>provided</scope>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.googlecode.json-simple</groupId>
        <artifactId>json-simple</artifactId>
        <version>1.1.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsp-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
        <artifactId>servlet-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.el</groupId>
        <artifactId>el-ri</artifactId>
        <version>1.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.poi</groupId>
        <artifactId>poi</artifactId>
        <version>3.14</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>com.sun.faces</groupId>
        <artifactId>jsf-impl</artifactId>
        <version>2.2.7</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-api</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.logging.log4j</groupId>
        <artifactId>log4j-core</artifactId>
        <version>2.5</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
        <artifactId>commons-lang3</artifactId>
        <version>3.4</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.primefaces</groupId>
        <artifactId>primefaces</artifactId>
        <version>6.0</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.python</groupId>
        <artifactId>jython-standalone</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.1b3</version>
    </dependency>
</dependencies>

<build>
    <finalName>ConfigurationConsole</finalName>
    <outputDirectory>src/main/webapp/WEB-INF/classes</outputDirectory>
    <plugins>
        <plugin>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</build>
```

faces-config.xml

```
<application>
<el-resolver>org.springframework.web.jsf.el.SpringBeanFacesELResolver</el-resolver>
</application>
```

web.xml

```
<servlet>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <servlet-class>javax.faces.webapp.FacesServlet</servlet-class>
    <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
</servlet>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/fases/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>/javax.faces.resource/*</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.jsf</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<servlet-mapping>
    <servlet-name>Faces Servlet</servlet-name>
    <url-pattern>*.xhtml</url-pattern>
</servlet-mapping>
<context-param>
    <description>State saving method: 'client' or 'server' (=default). See JSF Specification 2.5.2</description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.STATE_SAVING_METHOD</param-name>
    <param-value>client</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <description>
        If comments are enabled, the copyright header will prevent the login form
        from working on Internet Explorer. Alternatively, you can remove the copyright
        header.
    </description>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_SKIP_COMMENTS</param-name>
    <param-value>true</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.servlet.jsp.jstl.fmt.localizationContext</param-name>
    <param-value>resources.application</param-value>
</context-param>
<context-param>
    <param-name>javax.faces.FACELETS_RESOURCE_RESOLVER</param-name>
    <param-value>com.igt.icc.configurationConsole.FaceletsResourceResolver</param-value>
</context-param>
<listener>
    <listener-class>com.sun.faces.config.ConfigureListener</listener-class>
</listener>
<session-config>
    <session-timeout>30</session-timeout>
</session-config>
```

Spring boot main class:

```
@SpringBootApplication
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@ComponentScan
public class ApplicationStarter extends SpringBootServletInitializer implements ServletContextAware
 {

/**
 *
 * @param args
 */
public static void main(String[] args) {
    SpringApplication.run(ApplicationStarter.class, args);
    try{
        //JSONPropertiesManager.getInstance().loadProperties();
        JSONPropertiesManager.getInstance().loadJSONProperties();
    }catch(Exception ex){
        ex.printStackTrace();
    }
}

@Override
protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder application) {
    return application.sources(ApplicationStarter.class);
}


@Bean
public FacesServlet facesServlet() {
    return new FacesServlet();
}


@Bean
public ServletRegistrationBean facesServletRegistration() {
  ServletRegistrationBean registration = new   ServletRegistrationBean(facesServlet(), "*.xhtml");
  registration.setName("FacesServlet");
  return registration;
}


@Bean
public ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener> jsfConfigureListener() {
    return new ServletListenerRegistrationBean<ConfigureListener>(
        new ConfigureListener());
}

@Override
public void setServletContext(ServletContext servletContext) {
    servletContext.setInitParameter("com.sun.faces.forceLoadConfiguration", Boolean.TRUE.toString());       
}
```

}

facesResourceResolver class, called into the web.xml :

```
public class FaceletsResourceResolver extends ResourceResolver {

private ResourceResolver parent;
private String basePath;

public FaceletsResourceResolver(ResourceResolver parent) {
    this.parent = parent;
    this.basePath = "/META-INF/"; // TODO: Make configureable?
}

@Override
public URL resolveUrl(String path) {
    URL url = parent.resolveUrl(path); // Resolves from WAR.

    if (url == null) {
        url = getClass().getResource(basePath + path); // Resolves from JAR.
    }

    return url;
}
```

and this is my project structure:

```
projectFolder


-src
       -main
            -java
            -resources
                - here i have copyed into META-INF the *.class and /pages/*.xhtml
            -webapp
```

In Netbeans and eclipse the application run correctly. But when i build it and try to start the jar the application start correctly but when i try to open the pages i receive a 404 not found, What did I do wrong ?

Comment: Your `web.xml` doesn't do anything. Also if I recall correctly JSF and Spring Boot only works for a war file. Next to that instead of hacking your own you might want to try [this](https://github.com/joinfaces/joinfaces) instead that autoconfigures and bootstraps JSF for you.

Comment: pages should be under webapp

Comment: Jens --- with the jar paxkajing for springboot the webapp folder will not be included into the app.jar so you need to copy files unde resources folder or add the webapp folder as resource-directory into the build section of the pom.

Comment: How is this PrimeFaces related? Does it work if you don't use PrimeFaces?

Comment: Primefaces is used only for a compoent in one page. I tried to remove it but still get the same error

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Solution**
Please follow this below folder structure as shown in below figure.

[image: FolderStructure]

Comment: This is exactly my structure... the only difference is that i have all folders bootstrap, css etc... directly under webapp and not under webapp/resources...

Comment: Please move under resources, while you are exposing as a war file, spring-boot will look for resources folder and let know.

Comment: Same problem... /pages/index.xhtml Not Found in ExternalContext as a Resource

Comment: OK guys i have solved it... as has sayd Praveen Spring boot look for resources folder but when you build the jar, the resources folder have to be copyied under the META-INF folder.