# spring boot - how to correctly define template locations?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

After struggling for some time with a Spring app (and spring boot, for that matter), it seems I'm finally about to get it working.

I have shifted through dependency resolutions and maven build already. Application starts (and very quickly!) but when I try to access

`localhost:8080`

I get the following browser message whenever I try to reach the application's landing page:

```
HTTP Status 500 - Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "home/homeNotSignedIn", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers
```

The `src/main/resources`folder is

```
src/main/resources
    static // CSS, IMG and JS
    templates // html
    application.properties
    log4j.properties
```

Now, I understand I may be mixing concepts, but on my `ApplicationConfiguration.java` I have this:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "b.c.g.c")
public class ApplicationConfiguration extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter {

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template resolver serving HTML 5")
    public ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver() {
        ServletContextTemplateResolver templateResolver = new ServletContextTemplateResolver();
        templateResolver.setCacheable(false);
        templateResolver.setTemplateMode("HTML5");
        templateResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        templateResolver.setPrefix("classpath:/templates/");
        templateResolver.setSuffix(".html");

        return templateResolver;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf template engine with Spring integration")
    public SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine() {
        SpringTemplateEngine templateEngine = new SpringTemplateEngine();
        templateEngine.addDialect(new SpringSecurityDialect());
        templateEngine.addDialect(new LayoutDialect(new GroupingStrategy()));
        templateEngine.setTemplateResolver(templateResolver());

        return templateEngine;
    }

    @Bean
    @Description("Thymeleaf view resolver")
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {

        ThymeleafViewResolver viewResolver = new ThymeleafViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setTemplateEngine(templateEngine());
        viewResolver.setCharacterEncoding("UTF-8");
        viewResolver.setCache(false);
        viewResolver.setOrder(1);

        return viewResolver;
    }

    // other beans
}
```

And, on `application.properties`, I have this:

```
spring.thymeleaf.check-template-location=true
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
spring.thymeleaf.mode=HTML5
spring.thymeleaf.encoding=UTF-8
spring.thymeleaf.content-type=text/html
spring.thymeleaf.cache=false
```

Though I see these excerpts tell the same thing, I bet one can go, right?

So, two questions, actually,

1) how to make sure Spring + Thymeleaf understand where to find the templates?

2) how to get the application to answer to `localhost:8080/appName` instead of `localhost:8080/`?

Comment: Is there a reason you're configuring any of that at all? That entire template resolver is the default autoconfiguration.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Recommended Approach**
I will first answer your second question

1. You have define the application.properties or application.yml (Yaml is better) file in src/main/resources. Spring-Boot comes with [default properties](http://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/common-application-properties.html) file where you can set your context path (look for webproperties), port everything.

   ```
    server.context-path=/<appname>
   ```
2. To answer your second question spring-boot you can refer the thymeleaf configurations in the properties file.

Comment: thanks, buddy! The context path works! I still can't reach the landing page, though...

Comment: Are you packing as a JAR file or WAR file?

Comment: Preveen, I'm packing as war.

Comment: please check the below link    (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/39013112/spring-boot-embed-tomcat-pages-index-xhtml-not-found-in-externalcontext-as-a/39013354#39013354)